# Optimizing Python scripts' running time from C#

Tags: python, c#, ironpython, processstartinfo

I apologize in advance if my question is badly formulated, for I don't know if what I need makes any sense.

I'm currently working on a c# project where I need to run several time the same python script from inside the program, but with different arguments each time.
For this, I'm not using IronPython, but the ProcessStartInfo class, for I understood that IronPython has some problem with certain packages I use. But this can change.

My problem is that although the python script is small and fast, it needs to import first a lot of packages, and this takes a lot of time. And therefore, my code is very slow, while 90% of the time is used to import python packages.
I can't work around the problem by running this python script a single time with many arguments.

So is there a way to "*open a permanent python console*" from c#, where I could import everything once, then run the small script with my first argument, get the result back in c#, then run the script a second time etc .... ? Or any other way to optimize this ?

Thanks for your help,

Astrosias.

Comment: I think you can use pipes between processes to transfer data between them

Comment: Could you give me a link explaining how to do this in my situation ?

Comment: Maybe this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: If you found a solution you can close the question

Comment: I didn't found a solution yet, but I think I'm close.
I'll close the subject as soon as I can post a working answer.

Comment: Well, in the end I didn't find any solution. Everything failed.